# How to modify new records for INSERT ON DUPLICATE in Mysql

Tags: mysql, on-duplicate-key

#### Situation

Imagine a table columns A,B,C with a unique key on B and C and an autoincrement primary key on A

When sending new values (B,C) (42,1) and this table already contains a row with B,C being 42 and 1 on lets say ID 10, then the Mysql Server will not allow this and return :

```
Duplicate Entry ... for key ... .
```

#### Problem:

I would like to act on this and modify (increment) the value for C, to 2, so (42,2) could be inserted.

#### Failed tried solution

I found the INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE UPDATE ... but this updates the existing record. not the new values.

1. Existing record may not be edited
2. I have no way to query the table beforehand, everything should be done in 1 query
3. incremented new values may also already exist, and thus should continue increment (c = 3..4..5...)

Any idea how this can be done ?

Comment: modify == updates. Not sure I understand. Show us the failed query using INSERT ON DUPLICATE UPDATE

Comment: And the error message

Comment: Could be useful to see the schema as well

Comment: What if there's already a (42,2)?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. I don't seen it as common feature on a database.
I had expirence with MySQL e Informix. I know which theses databases have a TRIGGER for some actions:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

I create a example with MySQL:

#### Schema

```
CREATE TABLE tb (A INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, B INT, C INT);
```

#### Trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER upd_c_column 
BEFORE INSERT ON tb
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.C = (
    SELECT DISTINCT IFNULL(
        (SELECT IF(COUNT(*) IS NULL, 1, COUNT(*) + 1) AS B_ocurrences
        FROM tb sub_tb 
        WHERE sub_tb.B = NEW.B 
        GROUP BY sub_tb.B), 1)
);
```

#### Insert test

```
INSERT INTO tb (B) VALUES (10), (10), (10), (10), (20), (20), (30);

SELECT * FROM tb;    
+----+----+---+
| A  | B  | C |
+----+----+---+
| 73 | 10 | 1 |
| 74 | 10 | 2 |
| 75 | 10 | 3 |
| 76 | 10 | 4 |
| 77 | 20 | 1 |
| 78 | 20 | 2 |
| 79 | 30 | 1 |
+----+----+---+
```

It resolve to INSERT... If you need do UPDATE ou DELETE you will need create others trigger with other strategies.

Answer (score -1):

You can use UPDATE C=C+1 in your ON DUP statement like this

```
INSERT <table> (A,B,C) VALUES(1,23,1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE C=C+1;
```

I assumed your table was like this?

```
CREATE TABLE `new_table` (
  `A` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `B` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `C` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`A`),
  UNIQUE KEY `BC_IDX` (`B`,`C`)
);
```

I then ran this INSERT

```
INSERT test.new_table (A,B,C) VALUES(1,23,1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE C=C+1;
```

RESULT

```
A   B   C
1   23  1
```

Then ran the same query again

```
INSERT test.new_table (A,B,C) VALUES(1,23,1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE C=C+1;
```

RESULT

```
A   B   C
1   23  2
```

And run query again....
RESULT

```
A   B   C
1   23  3
```

Comment: @user207421 If you look closely this is an INSERT. But OP also said they wanted to increment the C column if the INSERT was trying to insert a Duplicate !!! See the sentence under **Problem**